# WPF FlowDocument Displays *Some* Images But Not Others

Tags: wpf, image, bitmapimage, flowdocument

This is the code I'm using to create the `Image` that I'm inserting into a `FlowDocument`.

```
private static Image GetImage(string url)
{
   if (url == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("url");

   if (!(url.StartsWith("http://") || url.StartsWith("https://") || url.StartsWith("ftp://")))
            return null;

   var uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
   var bmpImg = new BitmapImage(uri)
   {
      CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand,
   };
   if (bmpImg.CanFreeze) bmpImg.Freeze();

   var img = new Image
   {
      Source = bmpImg,
      Stretch = Stretch.Uniform,
      Height = 120,
      Width = 120,
   };

   return img;
}
```

When I create a document and insert an image from my server with

```
Designer.CaretPosition.Paragraph.Inlines.Add(image);
```

everything works fine - image displays as expected.  Also, [the main Google Logo image](https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png) works fine, but [the HackaDay Logo](https://s0.wp.com/wp-content/themes/vip/hackaday-2/img/logo.png) and others just display a blank image.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: I think that some web have [hotlink prevent](http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/). It could be a reason for that.

Comment: @ganchito55 looks like that's it.  Post as answer and I'll accept.

Comment: thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that some websites have [hotlink protection](http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/). For example in my website I can link a photo in every page that it is in my domain and it works well, however if you try to link a photo in other domain, the photo doesn't load.